# Java - org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 eliminate new line characters

Tags: java, certificate, base64

I'm facing the following problem when replacing `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.

I'm working with `X509Certificate` and i need to use `Base64` to encode byte array which is obtained by the result of `java.security.cert.Certificate.getEncoded()`

It looks that the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` eliminate new line characters while the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` keep it, see the code below:

```
String certString =  Base64.encodeBase64(certificate.getEncoded());
```

VS

```
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();          
String certString = encoder.encode(certificate.getEncoded());
```

I know that there is an option to use `encodeBase64Chunked` but the default is 76 characters and in addition there is an option to define lineLength and lineSeparator but i don't want to use fixed length but to use my input - `certificate.getEncoded()` that including the end of line characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Test
public void testBase64() {
String str = "a string with some\n\n newlines";
try {
    // To base 64
    String base64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(str.getBytes("UTF8"));

    // From base 64
    byte[] clear = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64);
    String clearText = new String(clear, "UTF8");

    assertEquals(str, clearText);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    fail();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it looks that it's working with the String but it's still eliminates new line characters in case that I'm using certificate.getEncoded() as an input.